# Asset file not in build using Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

My app has a sample data file of a private type that has been included with it since the app was originally built for Android 2.3. The code that references it is like so:

```
Resources res = mCtx.getResources();
AssetManager assMan = res.getAssets();

try {
    is = assMan.open(DB_SAMPLE);

    // stuff that copies to destination...
}
catch (IOException e) {
    stat = false;
}
```

What happens with builds from Android Studio 3.0.1 is that the assMan.open method jumps to the exception handler with a "File not found" error. The asset folder and file are definitely there, and based on a similar question I deleted and recreated the asset folder and copied the file back into it. In the Project view pane the "assets" folder is directly under "main" and has the same icon as the "res" folder. The project now targets SDK 26, but this failure occurs also on all older Android builds that I've tried.

Is there something I have to do to specifically get my file to be recognized, or has something else changed? Or it is just a bug?

Question closed: Neglected to try doing a Clean Project, thinking that Rebuild All would include doing this. The assets folder is now in the APK and all is working.

Comment: In Android Studio, use the APK Analyzer to confirm that your asset is indeed in the APK and are not somehow being dropped by the build process.

Comment: Indeed, there is no assets folder in the APK, whereas it is in the APKs from earlier versions of Studio. I only do Android development sporadically these days, so the last time was probably a few releases ago.

Comment: Perhaps the `assets/` directory is in the wrong spot (should be in `main/src/`, usually) or something in your Gradle file is telling Gradle some other spot for assets than the norm.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue as to how to find or fix an error like that. I'm wondering if it could be a problem with a project that started out targeting Android 2.3 several years ago (based on your book, BTW) and has been migrated upwards to succeeding versions of the build tools. But it definitely worked when I last built it in Nov '17 before upgrading to the newest Studio in late December.

Comment: "Unfortunately I have no clue as to how to find or fix an error like that" -- edit your question and post a screenshot of your project tree showing where `assets/` is, and post the contents of your module's `build.gradle` file. Or, compare your project to others that have `assets/`, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/PDF/PdfJS), to see what differences there are in terms of `assets/` location and Gradle configuration.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this, but I neglected to do a Clean on the project before rebuilding. That worked, all is well, thanks for your time (are you really on here 24/7 or do you have an AI robot giving answers? :-).

Comment: "are you really on here 24/7 or do you have an AI robot giving answers?" -- "or"? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Lesson learned not for the first time: When in doubt, always do a Clean Project before rebuilding a release. The "assets" folder is back in the APK where it belongs.

Comment: That is rather odd. While cleaning a project often helps with code or resource issues, this is the first that I have heard of it addressing an issue with assets. But, I'm glad that it is working for you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above sometimes after several builds using AS(Android studio) ,some asset ressources such as images were partially copied in apk,
then a simple **Clean Project** before **Build APKs** should fix this behavior as i can confirm from my situation
[image]

As you can see, after strugling tryng to find out why i got IO exception everytime i run the application, i thought it was the code but **it happens files were not present in the apk due to build process**.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: V_Line.png 05-06 14:58:22.256 E/PTL_EmailSender( 3344):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method) 05-06 14:58:22.256 E/PTL_EmailSender( 3344):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:374) 05-06 14:58:22.256 E/PTL_EmailSender( 3344):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:348) 05-06 14:58:22.256 E/PTL_EmailSender( 3344):    at com.pixeemedical.portal.email.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:99)`

missings assets inside apk:

[image]

Be Aware AS 3.4.1 is not that robust when handling ressources data of build.